# Tabla de verdad Python

Tags: python, tablas, tabla-dinámica

A continuación detallo el proyecto, el enfoque que le estoy dando y el problema. Estoy utilizando conocimientos muy básicos de Python, desconozco en su totalidad el uso de herramientas como Numpy, intento dominar esto para luego continuar.

Estoy creando una función que construya una tabla de verdad, pero un poco compuesta, me explico, a la función yo le ingreso como parámetros la cantidad de variables y la cantidad de valores que pueden tener esas variables (la variable x puede llega a valer 1,rojo,5,perro, en total serian 4 valores) la función con estos datos debería construirme una lista con todas las variaciones posibles. En formato de tupla o lista de cada linea, de tal manera que al recorrerla con un ciclo for se vería representada como una tabla de verdad.

por ejemplo:

Así quedaría la lista:

```
[("0", "0"),("0", "1"),("1", "0"),("1", "1")]
```

Con ciclo for:
00
01
10
11

Me pareció que era menos complicado crear primero la primera columna y a partir de allí crear el resto, ya que el orden de los ceros y unos de todas las columnas será diferente.

Con el código a continuación obtenemos perfectamente la primera columna de la izquierda (le podemos introducir la cantidad de variables y variaciones que sea y creara la primera columna en orden)

**El problema:** Como hago para repetir el proceso en la(s) columnas siguientes teniendo en cuenta que no será una cantidad de variables fijas (todo el orden de la tabla dependerá de la cantidad de variables y variaciones ingresadas).

**Datos de Entrada:**

- variables = La cantidad de variables que tendrá la tabla
- enteros = Este cálculos nos dirá cuantas veces seguidas irá cada valor de las variables por columna.

según el ejemplo de arriba sería [2, 1]

- listax = la lista que contendrá las lineas en forma de tupla o lista.
- permutaciones = calcula la cantidad de combinaciones posibles (numero de filas)
- variaciones = Los valores que pueden tener las variables

---

```
def crea_tabla(n1, n2):  
    variables = n2  
    enteros = []  
    listax = []  
    permutaciones = n1 ** n2  
    permutaciones2 = permutaciones  
    while permutaciones2 > 1:  
        permutaciones2 //= n1  
        enteros.append(int(permutaciones2))  
    for B_1 in range(0, permutaciones):  
        listax.append([])  
    def funcion1(num):  
        A = next(iter(enteros))  
        temp = num * A  
        return temp  
    def funcion2(num):  
        num.append(next(B))  
        return num  
    temp = "".join(list(map(funcion1, variaciones)))  
    B = iter(temp)  
    C = list(map(funcion2, listax))  
    return listax  
variaciones = "013"  
print(crea_tabla(3,2))
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Como hago para repetir el proceso en la(s) columnas siguientes teniendo en cuenta que no será una cantidad de variables fijas (todo el orden de la tabla dependerá de la cantidad de variables y variaciones ingresadas).

Comment: Ok, ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Obtienes un error? ¿Qué te impide hacerlo?

Comment: Bueno de intentar e intentado un montón xD, lo que mas se acercó fue un for que hice para agregar item pero a la segunda posición de cada tupla, pero me agregaba los mismos datos. No encuentro la manera de hacer todo ese proceso único(Individual) para que cree columnas en función de los dos datos que da la lista enteros.

Comment: Te doy un ejemplo para que me entiendas mejor, si yo indico que tengo 2 variables que pueden tener 3 valores distintos en mi caso (0 1 y 3). la función me calcula que serán 9 combinaciones posibles. "enteros" lo que calcula es el orden de los valores en la tabla para este ejemplo seria enteros = [3, 1] quiere decir que la variable1(columna 1) tendra 000111333 y la variable2(columna2) tendrá 013013013. lo que no logro es crear las columnas con un algoritmo para que la función reciba la cantidad de variables que sea y haga el orden de cada columna, con el código de arriba logro solo la columna 1

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

- Sacar iter(enteros) de  "funcion1(num)" [Esto con el fin de evitar que comiencen a iterar desde el inicio cada vez que se llama a la función]
- Ordenar enteros en reversa e iterarlo con iter() [esto para multiplicarlo con la salida de "temp" y poder completar la cantidad de caracteres por columna]
- crear un bucle for "for i in range(variables):" y ejecutar las funciones map dentro dentro de el. [para construir tantas variables(columnas) como necesitemos]
- Nota: debajo dejo el código completo por si lo desean utilizar como módulo. [Notarán que "simplifiqué" un poco el código para que sea mas fácil de leer, las "funciones 1 y 2" son sustituidas por las funciones lambda ].

```
def variaciones(n1, n2):
    '''
    Calcula la cantidad de permutaciones posibles
    formato:  variaciones(n1, n2)
    n1 = Cantidad de valores que pueden tener las 
    variables
    n2 = cantidad de variables
    '''
    return n1 ** n2

def crea_tabla(n1, n2, variaciones):
    '''
    Construye la tabla de verdad
    formato: crea_tabla(n1, n2, variaciones)
    n1: Cantidad de valores que pueden tener las 
    variables
    n2 = cantidad de variables
    variaciones: lista con los valores que pueden
    tener las variables, ejemplos: ["0","1","3"], 
    ["@", ".", "a"], ["U", "7", "+"]
    Nota: variaciones solo es compatible con valores
    de un solo caracter
    '''
    listax = []
    variables = n2
    enteros = []
    permutaciones = n1 ** n2
#---------------------------------------------
    '''
    Calcula "enteros". Es el orden de las variaciones
    en la tabla
    '''
    permutaciones2 = permutaciones
    while permutaciones2 > 1:   
        permutaciones2 //= n1
        enteros.append(int(permutaciones2))
#---------------------------------------------
    '''
    Le Agrega a listax tantas filas como combinaciones
    existan
    '''
    for B_1 in range(0, permutaciones):
        listax.append([])
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
    '''
    recorre la cantidad de variables que sean y añade columna por 
    columna basandose en el orden de enteros
    '''

    I_enteros = iter(enteros)
    enteros_reverso = reversed(enteros)
    I_enteros_reverso = iter(list(enteros_reverso))
        
    for i in range(variables):
        
        A = next(I_enteros)
        B = next(I_enteros_reverso) 

        X = "".join(list(map(lambda num: num * A , variaciones)))
        X2 = X * B
        I_X2 = iter(X2)
        Y = list(map(lambda listax: listax.append(next(I_X2)), listax))
    
#-------------------------------------------------------------------        
    return listax
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema: tienes una cantidad de variables. Las variables toman valores en el mismo limitado conjunto de valores.

Por comodidad, usare (0, 1, 2, ... n) para representar los valores que puede tomar una variable. Esto es lo mismo que decir que la variable es un digito base-N.

Si tengo varias variables y las coloco una tras otras, tengo un valor en base-N.

Ejemplo: dos variables que pueden tomar valores 0, 1, 2, lo que me da valores:

```
00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22
```

**Solución:**

1. El valor inicial es cero.
2. En cada iteración le sumo uno a este valor. La suma se hace en base-N.
3. Cada resultado parcial es una combinación válida. Cada dígito representa el valor de una variable.

**Código**

```
def crear_tabla(num_valores, num_variables):
    valor = [0] * (num_variables + 1)
    while True:
        normalizar(valor, num_valores)
        if valor[0]: # Overflow
            break
        for val in valor[1:]:
            print(val, end=' ')
        print()
        #   Sumar 1 al valor
        valor[-1] += 1
```

Usamos una lista de enteros para representar el conjunto de variables. Cada posición en la lista representa una variable distinta.

La lista tiene un elemento adicional para manejar el caso de overflow en la suma. El proceso termina cuando se `valor[0]` es distinto de cero, o sea, se ha producido un `overflow` en la suma y hemos probado todas las combinaciones.

En cada iteración sumamos uno a la variable de la derecha y luego llamamos a `normalizar()` para propagar correctamente la suma.

```
def normalizar(valor: list[int], base: int):
    for i in range(len(valor)-1, 0, -1):
        if valor[i] == base:
            valor[i] -= base
            valor[i-1] += 1
        else:
            break
```

La función normalizar revisa cada dígito, de derecha a izquierda. Si el dígito sobrepasa el valor base, se le resta la base y se agrega uno al digito de la izquierda.

**Demo**

```
def normalizar(valor: list[int], base: int):
    for i in range(len(valor)-1, 0, -1):
        if valor[i] == base:
            valor[i] -= base
            valor[i-1] += 1
        else:
            break


def crear_tabla(num_valores, num_variables):
    valor = [0] * (num_variables + 1)
    while True:
        normalizar(valor, num_valores)
        if valor[0]:
            break
        for val in valor[1:]:
            print(val, end=' ')
        print()
        #   add i to valor
        valor[-1] += 1
#   Cuatro variables, cada una puede tomar valores 0, 1 y 2.
crear_tabla(3, 4)
```

produce:

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 2 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 2 
0 0 2 0 
0 0 2 1 
0 0 2 2 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 2 
0 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 
0 1 1 2 
0 1 2 0 
0 1 2 1 
0 1 2 2 
0 2 0 0 
0 2 0 1 
0 2 0 2 
0 2 1 0 
0 2 1 1 
0 2 1 2 
0 2 2 0 
0 2 2 1 
0 2 2 2 
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 2 
1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 1 
1 0 1 2 
1 0 2 0 
1 0 2 1 
1 0 2 2 
1 1 0 0 
1 1 0 1 
1 1 0 2 
1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 2 
1 1 2 0 
1 1 2 1 
1 1 2 2 
1 2 0 0 
1 2 0 1 
1 2 0 2 
1 2 1 0 
1 2 1 1 
1 2 1 2 
1 2 2 0 
1 2 2 1 
1 2 2 2 
2 0 0 0 
2 0 0 1 
2 0 0 2 
2 0 1 0 
2 0 1 1 
2 0 1 2 
2 0 2 0 
2 0 2 1 
2 0 2 2 
2 1 0 0 
2 1 0 1 
2 1 0 2 
2 1 1 0 
2 1 1 1 
2 1 1 2 
2 1 2 0 
2 1 2 1 
2 1 2 2 
2 2 0 0 
2 2 0 1 
2 2 0 2 
2 2 1 0 
2 2 1 1 
2 2 1 2 
2 2 2 0 
2 2 2 1 
2 2 2 2 

Process finished with exit code 0
```